# Set imported certificate p12 to always be trusted in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate, p12

I have generated a certificate in `p12` format in MacOS X and imported it into default keychain using:

```
sudo security import ./keystore.p12 -P password
```

But that certificate is non trusted, all fields setting in value `no value specified`:

[image]

How may I set trust for `ssl` to Always trust using command line?

I tried to use this command but it doesn't work for `p12` ceritificate:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -p ssl ./keystore.p12
>>SecCertificateCreateFromData: Unknown format in import.
>>Error reading file keystore.p12
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you solve the issue?

Comment: @rraallvv, no I didn't :\

Answer (score 0):

1. Import p12 into keychain with -A ("Allow all apps to access")
2. Export public certificate from p12
3. Import public certificate into keychain with trustAsRoot option to make it "Always Trust"

This is only one way as i can see

```
sudo security import <p12_certificate> -k "$HOME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain" -P <p12_certificate_password> -A
sudo openssl pkcs12 -in <p12_certificate> -clcerts -nokeys -password pass:<p12_certificate_password> -out pub.crt
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustAsRoot -k "$HOME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain" pub.crt
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried below. It worked for me

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certificate>
```